# Related rates sloped swimming pool understanding

Tags: calculus, derivatives

So I have this question here:

[image]

I solved it and here is my work:

[image]

I'm having trouble with the wording though. For part a for instance, what number would I substitute in for h? 2.5 m or 0.5 m?

My understanding is that the pool has drained by 2.5 m so I sub in that value. Other's are saying that 2.5 m means that 0.5 m has drained. Which understanding is right? Thanks

Comment: When the pool is 2.5 m deep, $l$ does not depend upon $h.$  It is at a constant $20.$ until the water level gets below $2m.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the pool is 2.5 m deep the water runs the full length of the pool.

The area of the surface of the water $=8\cdot 20 = 160 m^2$

$\frac {dv}{dt} = 160 \frac {dh}{dt} = -1$

When the pool is 1 m deep the water makes is half way to the shallow end.

The area of the surface of the water $=8\cdot 10 = 80 m^2$

$\frac {dv}{dt} = 80 \frac {dh}{dt} = -1$

The water level is now falling twice as fast.

Comment: Thank you very much for clarifying the length issue.